# Расчет максимального количества IP-адресов в подсети

Tags: сеть, ip

> Маска сети для IPv4 адресации ­– это 4-х байтное число, которое делит IP адрес на адрес сети (первая часть) и адрес узла (вторая часть). Для части IP адреса, соответствующей адресу сети в маске сети содержатся двоичные единицы, а для части IP адреса, соответствующей адресу узла в маске сети содержатся двоичные нули. IP адрес, в котором в части адреса узла содержатся только двоичные нули – служебный адрес сети. IP адрес, в котором в части адреса узла содержатся только двоичные единицы – адрес ограниченного широковещания. Эти два адреса нельзя использоваться для адресации узлов.

Какое максимальное количество IP адресов для узлов доступно в сети с маской сети «255.255.248.0» ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В маске 11 младших разрядов нулевые

Поэтому число узлов (2 ^ 11) - 2 = 2046 ( 0 и -1 в адресе хоста - бродкаст)

Comment: спасибо, пока не знаю правильный ли это ответ или нет . а можете обьяснить по подробней, я если честно не понял вообще..!

Comment: Так в Вашем описании маски сети **все очень подробно**. Маска это запись нулей и единичек в 4-х байтах, только записанная десятичными числами для каждого байта. Переводите ее в шестнадцатиричное представление и смотрите правые нулевые разряды. У Вас их 11 (8 + 3) - это биты под адрес хоста.

Все единички там - однозначно бродкаст, нули раньше тоже были бродкаст, сейчас в XP ping говорит "некорректный адрес" а в linux просит добавить флаг -b. Поэтому минус два адреса для хостов.

--

Как надо "по науке" считать - точно не знаю.